# Return child array using Array.Map() in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

My Data from API looks like below,

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "appName": "string",
    "defaultAction": "string",
    "defaultMessage": "string",
    "rules": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "version": "string",
        "brand": "string",
        "action": "string",
        "message": "string"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "version": "string",
        "brand": "new brand",
        "action": "string",
        "message": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried like below to read child array from Parent Array from State to bind to table

```
const { posts } = this.state;
console.log(posts);
   const rule_list = posts.map(rules => {
  console.log(rules);
});
```

But I see it still returns complete array rather than only child element.Can someone  help me here.

Comment: What `console.log(posts);` is prints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules is complete element at particular index, You need to access the property you want to access i.e `rules.rules`

Or you can [**Destructuring_assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let data = [ { "id": 1, "appName": "string", "defaultAction": "string", "defaultMessage": "string", "rules": [ { "id": 1, "version": "string", "brand": "string", "action": "string", "message": "string" }, { "id": 2, "version": "string", "brand": "new brand", "action": "string", "message": "string" } ] } ]

const rule_list = data.map(({rules}) => {
  console.log(rules);
});
```

Comment: Hi, if I have 2 parent nodes and child nodes then its returning all the child nodes of both parent nodes. Anything missing here? my API results like below
[
  {
    "id": 1,   
    "rules": [
      {
        "id": 1,       
      },
      {
        "id": 2,       
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,    
    "rules": []
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `rules` property of each post item to get the child `rules` array as below.

```
posts.map((post) => {
   console.log(post.rules);
});
```

if you want to form a rules array from all posts, you can do that as below:

```
const rule_list = posts.map((post) => {
        let { rules } = post;
        if(rules && rules.length > 0) {
            return rules;
        }
    });
console.log(rule_list);
```